# Get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to create NSSpeechSynthesizer instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I get "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and I can't figure out why

Here is my interface

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface AppController : NSObject {
    NSSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynth;
}
```

and implementation

```
#import "AppController.h"


    @implementation AppController

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];

         // HERE I GET Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
         speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
        return self;
    }
    @end
```

I have included Cocoa and AppKit framework

Comment: As Nekto suggests in comments, there is something missing from this code. As it is written above, this would not crash. What else have you removed for simplicity?

Comment: How are you initializing AppController, it it in a XIB?  This code is correct as written, so the bug must be external to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if `self` is not nil in `init` methods before changing values of iVars:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I know that just remove it for simplicity. Anywhay thats not a problem in my case.